# Call PHP function with javascript with a javascript parameter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, function, parameters

I have this simple javascript which calls a PHP function flawlessly:

```
var showFeedPHP = "<?php showFeed($link, $category, $siteVersion, $cookie_index, $myuserlevel, $perPage, $showFrom); ?>";
$( "#sectionPosts" ).append( ""+showFeedPHP+"" );
```

I would like the last paramter, $showFrom, to be a javascript variable.

However, this version doesn't work and will just set the last parameter to the text string "+showFromJS+" :

```
var showFromJS = 10;
var showFeedPHP = "<?php showFeed($link, $category, $siteVersion, $cookie_index, $myuserlevel, $perPage, "+showFromJS+"); ?>";
$( "#sectionPosts" ).append( ""+showFeedPHP+"" );
```

I would like to use a javascript variable for declaring one of the php function parameters, but how?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax in this case here is a sample

```
    var showdeed= function(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/php/file/showFeed',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {link:link,
          category:category,...},
            success: function(data) {
                $( "#sectionPosts" ).append( ""+data+"" );

            }
        });

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'd hoped this could be done with the php function call that I had which worked - because I use this PHP function (as a true PHP function, meaning I call it traditionally using PHP) elsewhere. The AJAX method requires that what's currently in my PHP function, is no longer a function - which means I'll either have to duplicate the functionality (using 2 files; one as a function, the other one for AJAX) or change my function calls to fx. a "include() or require()". I'd hoped to avoid that...

Comment: Btw. I've ended up using the method you show here, with the small variation that I use POST rather than GET.

Answer (score 0):

You must use AJAX to achieve your objective

```
function loadData() {
    $.ajax({
    url: "path_to_showfeed.php?var1="+<?php echo json_encode($link);?>+"&var2="+<?php echo json_encode($category);?>+"&var3="....
    }).done(function(data) { 
    $( "#sectionPosts" ).append( ""+data+"" );
   });

 }
```

Also add this line to your head section

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer; I'd hoped this could be done with the php function call that I had which worked - because I use this PHP function (as a true PHP function, meaning I call it traditionally using PHP) elsewhere. The AJAX method requires that what's currently in my PHP function, is no longer a function - which means I'll either have to duplicate the functionality (using 2 files; one as a function, the other one for AJAX) or change my function calls to fx. a "include() or require()". I'd hoped to avoid that...

Comment: The use of AJAX doesn't dictate that your PHP function be changed at all @jakobdam You can place a PHP function in a file that can be called from any AJAX request on any page.

Comment: @jakobdam as rightly said by Jay you can create an another php file and place the required php function in that php file. Also I don't find any problem in creating a different file